# Grab parameter in html with highest value

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I have `$html`:

```
$html = '<div>
<a href="./?pg=99"></a>
<a href="./?pg=32"></a>
<a href="./?pg=95"></a>
<a href="./?pg=1"></a>
//etc
';
```

How do I skim through it and grab the highest value of `pg`? So in above case, we get:

```
$result = 99;
```

Potential approach is to via `preg_match_all()` and regex locate `/?pg=` cases, order them and grab the highest numeric value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to escape `./?` (resulting in `\.\/\?`) characters to get the numbers correctly, use the `U` flag for consecutive links, and then use [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php):

```
//                           number --v              U --v
preg_match_all('/<a.*href="\.\/\?pg=(\d+)".*>(?:.*)<\/a>/U', $html, $matches);

// numbers are our capture group 1 --> $matches[1]
$result = max($matches[1]);

var_dump($result);
// 99
```

No need to order the numbers.

Comment: I approve of this answer.

Comment: This is the one my friend.

Comment: This regex works with links having content but will fail if the link has more attributes than the href. I can improve that if needed.

Comment: Ah you are correct, I just saw this tested on the live site. Can you please improve the regex?

Comment: @AymDev Did you have a chance to add the adjustment? Thanks!

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Done, you can add other attributes before and after the href

Comment: @AymDev Will need to bother you again. Looks like it is [not working properly](https://ideone.com/nuLedG). In that example, `194` should  be the highest value. Do you know why it's not working in this case? EDIT: So when it has attributes, it doesn't work.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Well, I had hard times with this one but now it works, just use the `U` flag as mentionned in my edited answer