# Targeting URLs with parameters

Tags: php, regex

I want to grab the URL with highest `pg` value:

```
$html ='
    <a href="http://example.com/?pg=1"></a>
    <a href="http://example.com/?pg=2"></a>
    <a href="http://example.com/?pg=3"></a>
';
```

I use this regex to locate the appropriate links:

```
preg_match_all('/<a.*href="\.\/\?pg=(\d+)".*>(?:.*)<\/a>/U', $html, $preg_matches);
```

Sometimes, the links include another parameter:

```
http://example.com/?pg=3&test=1
```

My question is, how do I adjust my regex so links with the added parameters are included as well?

Comment: You have already asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945868/grab-parameter-in-html-with-highest-value), isn't that the same question?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, this question is targeting URLs with multiple parameters.

Comment: `\.` matches a dot. You must match any chars other than `"` with `[^"]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It does not include URLs with multiple parameters. Try adding `<a href="http://example.com/?pg=4&test=1">a</a>` to the `$html` variable and you will see.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you please post an answer to demonstrate this? Thanks.

Comment: A regex solution is not actually recommended. If the current one is that difficult for you to fix, why use regex by all means? You might use something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/3OihCO/1), but it will still fail to work in some cases although it should work in a lot more cases than your current one. Using a DOM parser is the best solution for such scenarios. XPath can also be coupled with regex if needed, but that does not seem necessary in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a DOM parser to find the anchors.
2. Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to parse the urls and get the query value
3. use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get the query values

Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$html ='
    <a href="http://example.com/?pg=1"></a>
    <a href="http://example.com/?pg=2"></a>
    <a href="http://example.com/?pg=3"></a>
';
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
        $url = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
        $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
        parse_str($query, $output);
        $pg = $output['pg'];
        //do something
}
```

Here's a helpful tutorial for PHP. http://htmlparsing.com/php.html

Also see here, why you should not use Regex for parsing html https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/81785

Answer (score 0):

```
        $html ='
        <a href="http://example.com/?pg=1"></a>
        <a href="http://example.com/?pg=2"></a>
        <a href="http://example.com/?pg=4&test=1"></a>
    ';
        preg_match_all('/<a[^>]+href=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>(.*)?<\/a>/', $html, $out);

        $result = null;
        foreach ($out[1] as $link){
            parse_str(parse_url($link, PHP_URL_QUERY), $atr);
            $result[$link] = $atr['pg'];
        }

        print_r($result);

//        "http://example.com/?pg=1" => "1"
//        "http://example.com/?pg=2" => "2"
//        "http://example.com/?pg=4&test=1" => "4"
```